# Get annotation of function reference

Tags: java, lambda, annotations, java-8

I would like to do so something like this:

```
foo(functionOfSomeObject)
{
    call functionOfSomeObject;
    get some annotations of functionOfSomeObject;
}
```

I dont want to use the `Method` class to pass `functionOfSomeObject` as this has to be retrieved by strings/reflection. Instead i would like to use a functional interface and lambda expressions like `myObject::method`. But is there a way to get the method annotations with this approach?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't believe you can do that...

Comment: Method references are just sugar. There is no metadata associated with them at the receiever since all you get back is an instance of a functional interface. Use reflection.

Comment: Well, I suspected this. I just really dislike referencing methods by strings.

Comment: So we have to use Reflection and Strings to reference these methods. This means we don't get compile time checking to ensure only existing methods are passed. That's a pity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `foo` method receives a value of some type. Given

```
void foo(FunctionalInterface func) {}
```

you can invoke it in any number of ways

```
foo(SomeType::someMethod);
foo(() -> {});
foo(new SomeImpl());
```

Within the body of `foo`, there's no way (and there shouldn't be) to know how the argument value was generated. You're not doing anything *extra* by providing a lambda or a method reference.

Use reflection to get the information you need. Note that with a method reference, the compiler is wrapping it into the method provided by the functional interface so you basically lose the method referenced (from a reflection point of view). You'll need to do this outside `foo`, where you actually have access to the method.